# Fourier transforms and Dirac delta function

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, dirac-delta

What is the Dirac delta function $\delta(t_1-t_2)$ in Fourier (frequency) space?

Comment: You mean $\delta(t-t_0)$ or something like that? (With $t$ being the variable and $t_0$ a constant.)

Comment: The actual question is to prove that δ(t1-t2) in Fourier space reads as δ(ω1+ω2). I am not sure as where to start and need some help!

Comment: OK, so it's the two-dimension Fourier transform that you're talking about? Anyway, the answer is trivial in the one-dimensional case: when you plug $\delta(t-t_0)$ into the integral defining the Fourier transform, you just pick out the value of $e^{-i\omega t}$ at the point $t=t_0$, i.e., $e^{-i\omega t_0}$. (Or something similar, depending on which convention you are using.) So getting a delta function in frequency space looks weird...

Comment: Or maybe not, since $\delta(t_1-t_2)$ isn't the same thing as $\delta(t_1-a)\delta(t_2-b)$, which is what I was thinking about...

Comment: Yes, it is probably the 2-dimensional Fourier transform.I do know the usual Fourier transform of a 1-D delta function. 
But I think I have to show that the Fourier transform of the given function is the dirac delta function in some form. (Like the Gaussian function which has the same form in real and Fourier space).

Comment: δ(a-b) = ∫δ(t-a)δ(t-b)dt is one of the known identities of the Dirac Delta function. Even with that, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What's your definition of $\delta(t_1-t_2)$?

Comment: I am having problems understanding the dirac delta function in this form.I think that δ(t1-t2) signifies the multivariable delta function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In this answer we normalize the [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) as
   $$\tag{1} \hat{\varphi}(\omega)~:=~(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \!d^nt~e^{-i\omega\cdot t}\varphi(t). $$
   Here the dimension will be $n=2$.
2. The relevant version of the [Dirac delta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta(t_1-t_2)$ (with two running arguments, so to speak) is here
   $$\tag{2} \delta[\varphi]~:=~\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \!d^2t~\varphi(t)~\delta(t_1-t_2)~:=~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!dt~ \varphi(t,t)$$
   for a [Schwartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) test function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{C}$.
3. There is a notion of [Fourier transform for tempered distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform). The Fourier transformed Dirac delta distribution is
   $$\hat{\delta}[\varphi]~:=~\delta[\hat{\varphi}]~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!dt~ \hat{\varphi}(t,t)
   ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\frac{dt}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \!d^2\omega~e^{-it(\omega_1+\omega_2)}~\varphi(\omega) $$
   $$\tag{3} ~=~\ldots ~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!d\omega~ \varphi(\omega,-\omega)~=:~\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \!d^2\omega~\varphi(\omega)~\delta(\omega_1+\omega_2).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But could you please expand on the 3rd step?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: What exactly happens in the "..." step?